# Load dropdown items from database

Tags: java, android

I am trying to show Micrsoft SQL Server Database results on a dropdown menu but get following exceptions.

```
09-06 09:39:09.790    6710-6725/? E/ERRO﹕ Connection Established
09-06 09:39:09.875    6710-6725/? D/ERRO﹕ Result set executed
09-06 09:39:09.875    6710-6725/? D/Database Strings﹕ Ground
09-06 09:39:09.876    6710-6725/? I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 6710 SIG: 9
09-06 09:39:09.888    5321-5727/? I/ActivityManager﹕ Process com.muchmore.www.dropdown (pid 6710) has died
09-06 09:39:09.899    5321-6064/? W/InputMethodManagerService﹕ Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@3962bb93 attribute=null, token = android.os.BinderProxy@2b0b1cb2
09-06 09:39:10.420    5635-5707/? W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Incorrectly called buildLayer on View: ShortcutAndWidgetContainer, destroying layer...
09-06 09:39:12.898    5321-5385/? D/TaskPersister﹕ removeObsoleteFile: deleting file=41_task.xml
09-06 09:39:12.898    5321-5385/? D/TaskPersister﹕ removeObsoleteFile: deleting file=41_task_thumbnail.png
09-06 09:39:12.947    5321-5321/? D/BackupManagerService﹕ Received broadcast Intent { act=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_CHANGED dat=package:com.google.android.gms flg=0x4000010 (has extras) }
09-06 09:39:12.947    5321-5321/? I/BackupManagerService﹕ Unbinding ComponentInfo{com.google.android.gms/com.google.android.gms.backup.BackupTransportService}
09-06 09:39:12.951    5321-5354/? I/InputReader﹕ Reconfiguring input devices.  changes=0x00000010
09-06 09:39:12.953    5321-5321/? I/BackupManagerService﹕ Binding to transport host ComponentInfo{com.google.android.gms/com.google.android.gms.backup.BackupTransportService}
09-06 09:39:12.963    5321-5321/? V/BackupManagerService﹕ Connected to transport ComponentInfo{com.google.android.gms/com.google.android.gms.backup.BackupTransportService}
09-06 09:39:12.964    5321-5321/? V/BackupManagerService﹕ Registering transport com.google.android.gms/.backup.BackupTransportService::com.google.android.gms/.backup.BackupTransportService = com.android.internal.backup.IBackupTransport$Stub$Proxy@28d42865
09-06 09:39:12.967    5549-5549/? W/GmsBackupAccountManager﹕ Backup account not found in gmscore.
09-06 09:39:12.980    5603-6729/? I/Backup﹕ [BackupTransportMigratorService] Starting migration...
09-06 09:39:12.981    5603-6729/? E/Backup﹕ [LegacyBackupAccountManager] Fail to get legacy transport context.
    android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException: Application package com.google.android.backup not found
            at android.app.ContextImpl.createPackageContextAsUser(ContextImpl.java:2139)
            at android.app.ContextImpl.createPackageContext(ContextImpl.java:2115)
            at android.content.ContextWrapper.createPackageContext(ContextWrapper.java:658)
            at android.content.ContextWrapper.createPackageContext(ContextWrapper.java:658)
            at com.google.android.gms.backup.as.<init>(SourceFile:47)
            at com.google.android.gms.backup.BackupTransportMigratorService.b(SourceFile:146)
            at com.google.android.gms.backup.BackupTransportMigratorService.onHandleIntent(SourceFile:81)
            at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
09-06 09:39:12.981    5603-6729/? W/Backup﹕ [LegacyBackupAccountManager] No google accounts found!
09-06 09:39:12.986    5549-5562/? W/GmsBackupAccountManager﹕ Backup account not found in gmscore.
09-06 09:39:12.993    5603-6729/? I/Backup﹕ [BackupTransportMigratorService] Component name not found : com.google.android.backuptransport/com.google.android.backup.BackupTransportService
09-06 09:39:12.994    5603-6729/? I/Backup﹕ [BackupTransportMigratorService] Component name not found : com.google.android.backup/com.google.android.backup.BackupTransportService
09-06 09:39:12.994    5603-6729/? I/Backup﹕ [BackupTransportMigratorService] Successfully migrated to use GMS BackupTransportService!
09-06 09:39:13.004    5720-6731/? D/PackageBroadcastService﹕ Received broadcast action=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_CHANGED and uri=com.google.android.gms
09-06 09:39:13.007    5720-6731/? I/PackageBroadcastService﹕ Null package name or gms related package.  Ignoreing.
09-06 09:39:13.022    5720-6048/? I/Icing﹕ updateResources: need to parse f{com.google.android.gms}
09-06 09:39:13.047    5549-5549/? V/GmsNetworkLocationProvi﹕ DISABLE
09-06 09:39:13.060    5549-5549/? I/GCoreNlp﹕ shouldConfirmNlp, NLP off. Ensuring opt-in disabled
```

I know that I should use Async instead of a normal thread but this is for testing part only. Later will change that. However this doesn't work. I am hiding the credentials for security sake.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    String choosenItem = "nothing";
    Connection connect;
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement;
    Statement st;
    String[] list;
    ArrayList<String> ArrayListing= null;

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    private Connection ConnectionHelper() {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                .permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        Connection connection = null;
        String ConnectionURL = null;
        try {
            Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
            Log.e("ERRO", "Class Loaded");
            ConnectionURL = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost/college_portal;encrypt=fasle;user=cp;password=cp@23;instance=MSSQLSERVER;";
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(ConnectionURL);
            Log.e("ERRO", "Connection Established");
        } catch (SQLException se) {
            Log.e("ERRO", se.getMessage());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e("ERRO", e.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("ERRO", e.getMessage());
        }
        return connection;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    connect = ConnectionHelper();

                    st = connect.createStatement();
                    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select Items from drop_down");
                    Log.d("ERRO", "Result set executed");
                    Array z = null;
                    String s;
                    while(rs.next()){
                        s = rs.getString(1);
                        Log.d("Database Strings", s);

                        ArrayListing.add(s);
                        Log.d("Feeding array", "did it");
                        //z = rs.getArray("Items");
                    }

                    //list  = (String[])z.getArray();

                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    Log.e("ERRO", "Runnable Error");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };

        Thread t = new Thread(r);
        t.start();

        Spinner dynamicSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.dynamic_spinner);

        String[] items = new String[] { "Chai Latte", "Green Tea", "Black Tea"};

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, ArrayListing);

        dynamicSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);

        dynamicSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                       int position, long id) {

                choosenItem = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                Log.v("item", choosenItem);
                TextView show = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.selectedItem);

                show.setText(choosenItem);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });


    }
}
```

Comment: have you initialized `ArrayListing` ??

Comment: @Panther yes ArrayList<String> ArrayListing= null;

Comment: Ha ha ha.... Before this call `ArrayListing.add(s);` ArrayListing  should be initialized with a value.. not null. Try `ArrayListing = new ArrayList<String>();`

Comment: ohh got it....so stupid of me didn't provided memory to array list

Comment: fixed thanks... ArrayList<String> ArrayListing = new ArrayList<String>();

Comment: @Panther but the text doesn't change when I select an item. Any idea why?

Comment: also i get ... after every item in list